# Is there any Norse mythological figure associated with victory?

Tags: norse, comparative

Is there an equivalent in Norse mythology to the goddesses [Nike](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nike_(mythology)) of the Greeks or [Victoria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victoria_(mythology)) of the Romans?

Any god or mythological being in Norse cult associated mainly with victory?

Comment: In a round-about way, I'm wondering if the valkyries are closest. They chose those fallen in battle to go to Valhalla. Obviously the chosen weren't victorious - they died, but that's only the mortal realm. In the wider sense they gained "victory" in being chosen by the valkyries to enter Valhalla, and presumably by being "heroes" for others to follow. A personal "victory" in the minds of those who lived by Norse mythology. Not one I'd care to achieve, but one they aspired to.

Comment: I don't think they would call it "victory." And I don't believe any of them did. Victory isn't the right word to describe death in battle.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**No, none that is exclusively associated with victory.**

The closest we get is probably Odin, who is said to be able to give victory in war. Note however, the [*Sigrdrífumál*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigrdr%C3%ADfum%C3%A1l), with accompanying prose introductions, in which it is told that Odin promised victory to the king Hjalmgunnar, but the valkyrie "Sigrdrífa" ('driver to victory'; she is actually Brynhilde) defeated him instead, so Odin's power is only worked through intermediaries. There is a part of [Njal's saga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nj%C3%A1ls_saga) in which a group of women weave witha gruesome set of tools: human skulls as loom-weigths, innards as the warp, etc, and sing of how they are valkyries and "weave victory".

If there would have been a norse personificiation of victory, the name would likely be *Sigr*.

Comment: What about the god [Týr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%C3%BDr)? I've found some examples of warriors carving [his rune](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiwaz_rune) on their weapons to obtain victory. Or was he like Odin, someone to whom commend yourself before battle, that not necessarily granted victory?

Comment: @Rodia Tyr was slowly going out of fashion (he likely used to hold the position Odin had), and by the end of the pagan age, he, and probably also Thor, was more likely a god you prayed to for personal success, while Odin was the god for kings and lords. If you went into a trial by combat, Tyr would be the appropriate god to pray for, if you were fighting a war with another king, you needed Odin's favor

Comment: I was hoping for a positive answer, but I'm quite convinced by your post. I'll wait a bit before accepting it, if you don't mind.

Answer (score -1):

Sigyn is prayed by a lot of pagans as the Goddess of Victory, since her name means "Friend of Victory" ;)

Comment: Hi Sunny, do you think you can expand on this? Can you add references or otherwise elaborate on your answer? Thanks!

Comment: Hello ! Of course, I’m glad to help. That theory is based first of all on Sigyn’s name. As you know, names in Norse mythology have meanings and are important. 
'Glut' means "glow" as she's a FIRE giantess. 'Angrboda' means "Bringer of grief", as she gives birth to the "monsters" that will bring Ragnarok and kill the gods. And 'Sigyn' means 'Friend of Victory'...
I read someone thought it was meant in an "ironical" way... but why would it be “ironical” for her, and not for the others?

Comment: Then, there is this one archeological remain we’ve got, that shows her and Loki, in their usual scene (Loki’s punishment). At the bottom (west side) of the Gosforth Cross (mid-11th century), located in Cumbria, England, you can see a representation of Sigyn, holding the bowl to protect Loki. If you look at her hair cut, it's typical of the Viking warriors when they went to battle... So yeah. Warrior!Sigyn for the win ^^'
In the links, you will find three articles I’ve found for you.

Comment: https://blog.vkngjewelry.com/en/sigyn/
                                                                           
https://www.altargods.com/post/sigyn-the-goddess-who-grants-victory                                                                      
                                                                 
https://www.vikingceltic.fr/blogs/news/sigyn-deesse-nordique-de-la-victoire

Comment: The article in French is really interesting, and talks about the Gosforth Cross. They also have this theory about the  “little friend” part of her name meaning she accompanied the warriors to war… as part of her duties as Goddess of Victory.
Nowadays, the theory that Sigyn is/was Goddess of Victory for the Norse mythology is so popular that if your just google “Norse goddess of Victory”, her name will come up first :p Just try!

Comment: Hi Sunny, can you edit all that (well, except perhaps the Marvel and modern stuff) in to the answer? I think it would make it a very solid answer, but StackExchange likes all the relevant information to be in the body of the answer, not the comments. I'm no expert on Norse myths, though I do know a bit of Old Icelandic.

Comment: I know, I tried to put everything in one post, but the website would not let me XD

Comment: Is it ok now? :) If you want my complete answer, I've posted it on tumblr :) Sorry for being so talkative! XD https://at.tumblr.com/jonquilclegane/sigyn-norse-goddess-of-victory/oetk68f8w8i3

Comment: I had no idea that Tumblr was thriving. I'll edit it later for you. Thanks for the info.